# MS Excel CHIINV function in XPages

Tags: ssjs

I am looking for some SSJS/java/lotus script code, equivalent to **MS excel CHIINV** function. If it is possible in XPages, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

Problem resolved. I found java library from following link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsci/

Here in the library, got statistical functions to perform CHIINV calculations.

Thanks